# Is the Million Songs Dataset available in .tsv or .csv format?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I came close with the following repo (select song_dataset.csv) (github.com/Taranveer/Million_Song_dataset) but when I loaded the dataset through Spark (a Hadoop variant), the result was a bunch of question marks:

> 14/12/30 04:02:51 INFO spark.SparkContext: Job finished: take at
>   :14, took 0.205963622 s tenSongs: Array[String] = Array(�HDF,
>   ?,
>   ????????????????????????���������T??????��������????????`???????????????�???????�???????????????????????????????
>   ???????(???????TREE????����������������????????????????(???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????HEAP????X???????8???????�???????????????metadata????????analysis????????musicbrainz?...

Also I think the public S3 bucket that was provided by the project at Columbia U is defunct (it was a temporary public bucket that launched a few years ago): http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/millionsong/blog/11-6-22-msd-hackreduce-boston-s3-bucket

Comment: can you please post some code snippet that what you are doing?Also are you getting any exception or just these question mark characters.I think you have missed some deserialization

Comment: Sure thing! I'm following Bilalaslam's tutorial (http://bilalaslam.com/how-to-process-a-million-songs-in-seconds/). I'm able to launch the Spark REPL and my first task is to take 10 records from the dataset:

val songs = sc.textFile("hdfs://master_dns:9000/msd");
val tenSongs = songs.take(10)

The result is the trifle of question marks I posted above.

Comment: Also for some reason I forgot to post the Repo link I used: https://github.com/Taranveer/Million_Song_dataset; file: song_dataset.csv. I'll edit that into the post too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading the wrong version of the dataset from the website you posted http://bilalaslam.com/how-to-process-a-million-songs-in-seconds/

> **The Data**
>
> For this blog post, we’re going to use the Million Song Dataset from Columbia University. The data is, unfortunately, in HDF5 format, which is not native to Hadoop or Spark. Spark makes it easy to parse TSVs or CSV. For the purpose of this blog post, we converted the data to TSV format and put it in an S3 bucket.

Notice the `HDF` at the start of your dataset `�HDF, ?, ????`.  That means you are trying to read an HDF5 file instead of the TSV.

Comment: Ahh.. I see. Well, that answers the question of why the dataset doesn't load properly. Thanks! Have you come across any .tsv/.csv versions of the datasets? Is there a good method to convert a bundle of .h5 files to .tsv/.csv? Thanks again!

Comment: @Andrew I've never actually used that dataset, so I don't know where you can get it.  As far as conversion... HDF is a hierarchical format so any conversion between that and a flat format such as TSV will require at least a little bit thought.  I don't know of any conversion software off hand.

Comment: Great! I've just decided to move on to a dataset in .tsv format already to save me the trouble of converting. That means figuring out prompts different from the one in the tutorial, but that shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 1):

Over at [Hifi](http://hi.fi) we have found the data from the Million Songs Dataset quite useful in building some of our initial recommendations algorithm prototypes, but to make the data actionable, having it in a simpler format (such as a csv) really simplifies things.

We've open sourced some initial work here:

https://github.com/rcrdclub/mm-songs-db-tools

specifically helpful for this question is this script `mmsongsdb_to_csv.py` that recursively walks a given directory and converts the metadata found in `*.h5` files into one single csv. Hope it helps!